# Highlight the table cells based on value on different tables

Tags: jquery

My problem is that I have two tables, and each table has a cell that the content is an input field and they need to match the same exact value in different tables. 
When the value doesn't match I need to highlight where is not matching.

The user only gonna receive this info when he clicks on a button to submit if the value doesn't match needs to be highlighted and he only can go to the next page when the value matches.

I can't highlight and I need to improve this code.

This is what I did so far:

```
$(".buttonThatUserClick").on('click', function() {

    var bdn = $('input[name*=returnitemqty]'); /* table A */
    var lgl = $('input[name*=replacementitemqty]'); /* table B */
    var arr = [];
    var brr = [];
    $(bdn).each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(lgl).each(function() {
        brr.push($(this).val());
    });

    var is_same = arr.length === brr.length && arr.every(function(element, index) {
        return element === brr[index]
    });

    if(is_same === false) {
         console.log('false')
    } else {
        console.log('woop')
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: Sadly this is work-related and it's big.

Comment: Basically is 2 tables ( A & B) and the system generates different rows based on the user data. The TR has a few TD inside and this TD with the input need to match with the other Table TD. They have different names as you can see on the code. The BDN is from table A and LGL is from table B.

Comment: Share some sample code or create jsfiddle for the same.

Comment: On which button user will click. I digit find any button with productable_txt class

Comment: I changed the button for the text SALES/REPLACEMENT ITEM. So click on the text to achieve the console.log

Comment: Run each on bdn in function extract number from the name i.e. 0/1/2... Then select replacementunitqty+extracted number and get value. Compare both values if equal than ok, otherwise do your stuff. Will update code asap.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot, Pradeep, wish you the best man!

Comment: most welcome, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Finally... Since `.every()` halts on the first `false` found...
Have to do the hightlighting in a separate loop... And leave the other comparison as is.

```
// Cell check and color hightlight
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i]!=brr[i]){
    lgl.eq(i).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});   // Red on error
    bdn.eq(i).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
  }
}
```

*(See edit history to view the previous attempt)*

[**Your CodePen updated**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/opGxaL?editors=1111)

Comment: If I have more than 1 TR to check only validates the first.. the others doesn't check

Comment: oups... hold on

Comment: Both tables highlights.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution for your problem:

```js
$(".productable_txt").click(function(){
    $('input[name*=returnitemqty]').each(function(){
      en = $(this).attr('name').replace('returnitemqty','');
      $(this).css({"background-color":"#FFFFFF"});
      if($(this).val()==$('input[name=replacementitemqty'+en+']').val()){
        console.log('Matched!');
      }else{
        //alert('Something wrong');
        $(this).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
        //return false;
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: This line: $('input[name=replacementitemqty'+en+']').css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});